# Vuex (or maybe just JS) chained promises in Actions and context/commit

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, es6-promise, vuex

We're having a hard time figuring out how context (or specifically { commit } is handled in chained promises with transpiled ES6 code. Below is one example of a Login action that authenticates and then `subscribes` using RxJS to the user as a stream. We need to commit several mutations throughout the process, but keep getting `commit is not a function` errors.

Does anyone know of or have an example of something like this or can anyone provide any basic guidelines on where and how context/commit are handled in this scenario - e.g. when can ES6 be used vs not, and/or where is context hoisted or not (if at all), and or is there a simpler approach to all this like maybe wrapping things all in a master promise?  Since we need to potentially commit at each step in the promise chain, we cannot see how some of this could work:

```
const actions = {
  login ({commit}, creds) { // need to commit here
    commit('toggleLoading')
    api.authenticate({
      strategy: 'local',
      ...creds
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      return api.passport.verifyJWT(result.accessToken)
    })
    .then(function ({commit}, payload) {  //need to commit here
      console.log(commit)
      return api.service('users').get(payload.userId)
      .subscribe(commit('setUser', user)) // need to commit here - but commit is not a function error
    })
    .catch(function ({commit}, error) {
      commit('setErr', `ERROR AUTHENTICATING: {$err.message}`) // need to commit here but commit is not a function error
      commit('toggleLoading')
    })
  }
```

All of the examples we find are way simplistic and only show one commit per action (or maybe 2 wrapped in an if). Any help or feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the callback functions in `.then` and `.catch` take a single argument, you've coded two ... however, `commit` from the `login` arguments is still in scope, so it's quite simple to fix

Your code can be simplified as follows

```
const actions = {
    login ({commit}, creds) {
        commit('toggleLoading');
        api.authenticate({strategy: 'local', ...creds})
        .then(result => api.passport.verifyJWT(result.accessToken))
        .then(payload => api.service('users').get(payload.userId).subscribe(commit('setUser', user)))
        .catch(function (error) {
            commit('setErr', `ERROR AUTHENTICATING: ${error.message}`);
            commit('toggleLoading');
        });
    }
```

Note: you have `{$err.message}` in the `.catch`, whereas I beleive that should be `${error.message}`

Comment: Slight change was need to chain the user after the subscribe, but this works. Thanks!